# Create data of frequency of interactions between variables using R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, zoo

I'll like to calculate a  table of frequency of dyadic interactions using R.  I need to count how many interactions between animals for each month and then, in total. A sample of the data is provided below:

```
#Create sample data
B1 <-data.frame(Animal = c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E"), Location = c(1,1,2,1,3,4,2,1,1,3,3,4,3,1,1,4,2,2,2,1,1,3,4,3,2), Month = c("Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Jan","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Feb","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Mar","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","Apr","May","May","May","May","May"))
```

Using this data, I want to be able to show animals present at a location monthly in pairs
For example, the expected result for the pairs using the locations should look similar to this for January:

```
#Sample extract for January
B1Jan <- data.frame(Animal1= c("A", "A","B") ,Animal2=c("B","D","D") )
B1Jan
  Animal1 Animal2
1       A       B
2       A       D
3       B       D
```

After extracting for each month, I want to be able to count the total number of interactions between each pair in total e.g. maybe the A-D interaction occurred 3 times in total.

What's the best way to do this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`, you can probably do something like:

```
library(data.table)

#convert into data.table
setDT(B1)

#create interaction between animals in the same location & month    
ans <- B1[, if (.N > 1L) transpose(combn(unique(Animal), 2L, simplify=FALSE)), 
    by=.(Location, Month)]

#change column names to desired column names
setnames(ans, paste0("V", 1L:2L), paste0("Animal", 1L:2L))

#sort animals so that A, B and B, A are the same
ans[, paste0("Animal", 1L:2L) := .(pmin(Animal1, Animal2), pmax(Animal1, Animal2))]

#count the number of interactions as requested
ans[, .(NumInteract=.N), by=c(paste0("Animal", 1L:2L))]
```

output:

```
   Animal1 Animal2 NumInteract
1:       A       B           1
2:       A       D           1
3:       B       D           3
4:       C       D           2
5:       A       C           1
6:       D       E           1
7:       B       C           1
```

Comment: Thanks @chinsoon12. This works. I also tried it using three "by" columns.

Comment: One more thing; At the moment, in my actual dataset, I have A to C and C to A represented as two different interactions. Is there a way to add a line to ensure that it counts A to C or C to A as the same pair, please?

Comment: @JokeO. I added a line to sort animals by each row. hth